# Python .py to .exe py2exe ERROR

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I made a python program. When i used py2exe to convert it to exe , it was converted . But when I run the program this error is shown:
ImportError: Dll load failed: The device is not ready.

This is the program :http://pastebin.com/kzpT71W5

Comment: I would start with the tutorial to make sure that's working first:http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: It is better to post the minimum verifiable code that illustrates your problem rather than linking to something offsite.

Comment: Check for this. You might be using 64 bit py2exe on 32 bit Python.